# Array PDO mySQL com Json erro na exibição

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, autocompletar

estou com uma grande dificuldade em json_encode

```
echo json_encode($autocomplete -> fetchAll(PDO :: FETCH_ASSOC));
```

eu estou fazendo um select do banco de dados até ai tudo bem, mas quando ele transfere os dados para este echo ai de cima, aparecem muitos caracteres que o javascript não está aceitando, como transformo a saida de cima que é exibido como abaixo

```
[{"user_name":"Roberto Monteiro"},{"user_name":"Dk Teclive"},{"user_name":"Fye Flourigh"}]
```

no formato abaixo que é aceito pelo javascript

```
["Roberto Monteiro", "Dk Teclive", "Fye Flourigh"];
```

ou seja, como posso transformar isso

```
[{"user_name":"Roberto Monteiro"},{"user_name":"Dk Teclive"},{"user_name":"Fye Flourigh"}]
```

e deixar neste formato

```
["Roberto Monteiro", "Dk Teclive", "Fye Flourigh"];
```

seja com php ou javascript, se possível, das duas formas, grato desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu javascript o primeiro passo é parsear a string enviada pelo php em um json válido, depois pode acessar o array assim: `lista[i].user_name` ou `lista[i]['user_name']` ou ainda pode usar o jquery para tornar `lista` um array simples(tambem é possível fazer com javascript puro).

```
var lista = JSON.parse('[{"user_name":"Roberto Monteiro"},{"user_name":"Dk Teclive"},{"user_name":"Fye Flourigh"}]');
var array_simples = $.map(lista, function (item) {
        return item.user_name;
    });
```

Comment: cara, você é um gênio, funcionou 100%, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez usando [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

`echo json_encode($autocomplete -> array_values(fetchAll(PDO :: FETCH_ASSOC)));`

Comment: olha, quando pus isso ai, toda minha página ficou branca, rsrs, piorou bastante, você consegue me ajudar neste quesito? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43291/pesquisa-din%C3%A2mica-com-json-php-mysql